How can I decompose a 3D rotation into one rotation about Z and one about an axis in XY?
How can I decompose a 3D rotation $T$ into one rotation about Z and one about an axis in XY, the latter with minimal angle?
Note: This is similar but not identical to How can I break down a rotation of known amount around a known axis into two rotations of unknown amounts around known axes? . In both cases, we decompose into two axis-angle-rotations but there, both axes are known, here only one is known.

What is a "rotation about XY"?

I suppose, rotation about XY is about an axis taken from XY plane ... Am I right?

Rotation about Z and rotation in XY are the same concepts. Can you please elaborate?

First find a non-zero vector $v = (v_1, v_2, 0)$ such that $Tv = (w_1, w_2, 0)=w$ for some $w_1, w_2$. Then find the rotation $R_z$ around the $Z$-axis such that $R_zv = w$. Then $R_z^{-1}T$ is a rotation around the line spanned by $v$ and $T = R_z(R_z^{-1}T)$. Also, $TR_z^{-1}$ is a rotation around the line spanned by $w$, and $T = (T R_z^{-1}) R_z$.
